# C pointers and objects as part of different classes

Tags: c++

I have relatively less experience with C++ coding, and I'm working on a project that requires me to use classes, pointers and objects in C++. I'm facing some basic problems while practising coding.

This is what part of my .cpp file looks like:

```
A::A(int x, int y):CD()
{
   //some code
}
B::B(int z):CD()
{
   //some code
}
```

If I need to pass values from A to B, how would I be able to do it in such a scenario? Could anyone please clarify and help me.

**Edit:** According to the code I have, CD is also defined as a class like A and B.

Comment: It would be better if u have explained about CD() ,no information is given about it

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Here A is a class and B is another class right,

Let's take a simple addition example

A(int x,int y)
{

b=new B(x+y);//let be a reference of class B
           //this will call B's constructor

}

---

B(int z)

{

this.z=z;//lets's assume that z is a variable in B class

}

Comment: Thanks, I understood it. I also have a line of code that says: A* p=new A(int x, int y). Why is the A* being used?

Comment: new A(int x,int y) ,using new memory gets allocated in heap 
memory and p is pointer which gets allocated in stack memory and we know that pointers are used for pointing to another variables,objects .So you will create a pointer of class A type and it's getting pointed to heap object of A                                                     Also A &p=new A(int x,int y) is valid in cpp.refer          https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pointers-vs-references-cpp/

Comment: Oh I see..Thanks!

Comment: This causes a memory leak if B doesn't delete itself. It is unusual to have a class existing by itself without a reference to it. @programmer_360 can you clarify the environment of the classes, i.e. their use and where they are used so we can help you finding a better solution, because I don't think this is what you want to do.

Comment: @birdfreeyahoo i just gave an idea to him.No one does a project without a cutting edge knowledge on it.Let's give a hope so that he can explore through it and that's how we earn the knowledge right!!